# The Powerset Monad

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors, monads

I am struggling to prove commutativity of the diagrams for the powerset monad in Category $\mathbb{Set}$.

1. To show that $\mu:\mathcal{P}^{2}\longrightarrow \mathcal{P}$ given by $\mu_{X}:\mathcal{P}^{2}(X)\longrightarrow\mathcal{P}(X)$, $\{A_{i}:i\in I\}\mapsto\bigcup_{i\in I}A_{i}$
   is a natural transformation, I must show that the diagram

$$
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\xrightarrow{\quad#1\quad}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\left\downarrow{\scriptstyle#1}\vphantom{\displaystyle\int_0^1}\right.}
%
\begin{array}{llll}
\mathcal{P}^{2}(X) & \ra{\mu_{X}} & \mathcal{P}(X)  \\
\da{\mathcal{P}^{2}(f)} & & \da{\mathcal{P}(f)} \\
\mathcal{P}^{2}(Y) & \ra{\mu_{Y}} & \mathcal{P}(Y) \\
\end{array}
$$
commutes, where $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ and $\mathcal{P}(f)$ is given by $A\mapsto f(A)$.

I can show that $$\mathcal{P}(f)(\mu_{X}(\{A_{i}:i\in I\}))=\mathcal{P}(f)\big(\bigcup_{i\in I}A_{i}\big)=\bigcup_{i\in I}f(A_{i})$$ 
How do I show that $$\mu_{Y}(\mathcal{P}^{2}(f)(\{A_{i}:i\in I\}))=\mathcal{P}(f)(\mu_{X}(\{A_{i}:i\in I\}))=\bigcup_{i\in I}f(A_{i})$$ Is there any trick on how to use $\mathcal{P}^{2}(f)$?

2. Also for the diagram

$$
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\xrightarrow{\quad#1\quad}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\left\downarrow{\scriptstyle#1}\vphantom{\displaystyle\int_0^1}\right.}
%
\begin{array}{llll}
\mathcal{P}^{3}(X) & \ra{\mu_{\mathcal{P}(X)}} & \mathcal{P}^{2}(X)  \\
\da{\mathcal{P}\mu_{X}} & & \da{\mu_{X}} \\
\mathcal{P}^{2}(X) & \ra{\mu_{X}} & \mathcal{P}(X) \\
\end{array}
$$
Is it always true that $\mathcal{P}\mu=\mu \mathcal{P}$? Or there is another simpler way of showing that $$\mu_{X}\circ\mathcal{P}\mu_{X}=\mu_{X}\circ\mu_{\mathcal{P}(X)}$$

I'd appreciate any form of help. Thank you

Comment: Your notation $\mu_X\wp$ in 2) is not correct. It should be $\mu_{\wp(X)}$ or $(\mu\wp)_X$.

Comment: Isn't it the $\mathcal{P}\mu_{X}$ that needs to be fixed?

Comment: No. We have $\mu_X:\wp^2(X)\to\wp(X)$. Then functor $\wp$ applied on this gives $\wp\mu_X:\wp^3(X)\to\wp^2(X)$. Further we have $(\mu\wp)_X:\wp^3(X)\to\wp^2(X)$ and there $(\mu\wp)_X$ is by definition the arrow $\mu_{\wp(X)}$

Comment: We start with natural transformation $\mu:\wp^2\stackrel{\bullet}{\to}\wp$. Then there are two natural transformations based on that: $\wp\mu:\wp^3\stackrel{\bullet}{\to}\wp^2$ and $\mu\wp:\wp^3\stackrel{\bullet}{\to}\wp^2$. The first has components $\wp\mu_X=\wp(\mu_X)$ and the second has components $\mu_{\wp(X)}$ for every object $X$. Both are arrows $\wp^3(X)\to\wp^2(X)$.

Comment: Ok thank you @drhab

Comment: With these components, particularly, this one "$\mu_{\mathcal{P}(X)}=(\mu \mathcal{P})_{X}$", do you perhaps know of any document where I can learn how to show it? I learnt earlier on about the two natural transformations that you have mentioned, but I haven't found anything on this component.

Comment: You could try [Joy of cats](http://katmat.math.uni-bremen.de/acc/acc.pdf) definition 6.3 on page 84.

Answer (score 7):

Note that, in general, we have
\begin{align}
\mathcal P(f)(x')&=\{f(x):x\in x'\}&
&x'\in\mathcal P(X)\\
\mu_X(x'')&=\bigcup x''\\&=\bigcup_{x'\in x''}x'\\
&=\{x:\exists x'(x\in x'\in x'')\}&
&x''\in\mathcal P^2(X)
\end{align}
hence, in particular,
\begin{align}
\mathcal P^2(f)(x'')
&=\mathcal P(\mathcal P(f))(x'')\\
&=\{\mathcal P(f)(x'):x'\in x''\}\\
\end{align}

For the fist question, note that
$$P^2(f)(\{A_i:i\in I\})=\{\mathcal P(f)(A_i):i\in I\}$$
hence the commutativity of the first diagram is equivalent to
$$\bigcup_{i\in I}\mathcal P(f)(A_i)=\mathcal P(f)\left(\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i\right)$$
which is true because both sides equals
$$\{f(a):\exists i\in I(a\in A_i)\}$$

For the second question, let $x'''\in\mathcal P^3(X)$.
Then
\begin{align}
(\mu_X\circ\mathcal P\mu_X)(x''')
&=\mu_X(\{\mu_X(x''):x''\in x'''\})\\
&=\bigcup_{x''\in x'''}\mu_X(x'')\\
&=\bigcup_{x''\in x'''}\bigcup_{x'\in x''}x'\\
&=\{x:\exists x'\exists x''(x\in x'\in x''\in x''')\}\\
\end{align}
on the other hand
\begin{align}
(\mu_X\circ\mu_X\mathcal P)(x''')
&=\mu_X\left(\bigcup x'''\right)\\
&=\bigcup\bigcup x'''\\
&=\bigcup\bigcup_{x''\in x'''}x''\\
&=\bigcup\{x':\exists x''(x'\in x''\in x''')\}\\
&=\{x:\exists x'\exists x''(x\in x'\in x''\in x''')\}\\
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you @Fabio_Lucchini. How did we get $$P^2(f)(\{A_i:i\in I\})=\{\mathcal P(f)(A_i):i\in I\}$$ The direct computation yields $$\mathcal{P}^{2}(f)(\{A_i:i\in I\})=\mathcal{P}(\{\mathcal {P}(f)(A_i):i\in I\})$$ Or am I missing something?

Comment: In general, for $x''\in\mathcal P(X)$ you have $\mathcal P^2(f)(x'')=\{\mathcal P(f)(x'):x'\in x''\}$ by definition.

Comment: I add a further explanation in my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is way clear now. But for the last part, did you use the fact that $$(\mu \mathcal{P})_{X}=\mu_{\mathcal{P}(X)}$$?

Comment: Yes, it is used in $(\mu_X\mathcal P)(x''')
=\bigcup x'''$

Answer (score 2):

In this answer $\cup$ is an operator on sets that sends every set to the union of its elements: $$A\mapsto\cup A:=\bigcup_{a\in A}a$$

Actually $\mu_X$ can be recognized as this operation restricted to $\wp^2(X)$.

---

1)

For $\mathcal A\in\wp^2(X)$ or equivalently $\mathcal A\subseteq\wp(X)$ we have:$$\mathcal A\stackrel{\mu_X}{\mapsto}\cup\mathcal A\stackrel{\wp(f)}{\mapsto}f(\cup\mathcal A)$$(as you already noted) and:$$\mathcal A\stackrel{\wp^2(f)}{\mapsto}\{f(A)\mid A\in\mathcal A\}\stackrel{\mu_X}{\mapsto}\cup\{f(A)\mid A\in\mathcal A\}$$

So in order to prove the commutativity it is enough to show that: $$f(\cup\mathcal A)=\cup\{f(A)\mid A\in\mathcal A\}=\bigcup_{A\in\mathcal A}f(A)$$

The obvious equivalence of the following statements show that:

- $x\in f(\cup\mathcal A)$
- $\exists y\in\cup\mathcal A\;[x=f(y)]$
- $\exists A\in\mathcal A[\exists y\in A[x=f(y)]]$
- $\exists A\in\mathcal A[x\in f(A)]]$
- $x\in\bigcup_{A\in\mathcal A}f(A)$

---

2)

Let $\mathcal A_i\in\wp^2(X)$ or equivalently $\mathcal A_i\subseteq\wp(X)$ for every $i\in I$.

Then we have:

$$\{\mathcal A_i\mid i\in I\}\stackrel{\wp(\mu_X)}{\mapsto}\{\cup\mathcal A_i\mid i\in I\}\stackrel{\mu_X}{\mapsto}\cup\{\cup\mathcal A_i\mid i\in I\}$$and:

$$\{\mathcal A_i\mid i\in I\}\stackrel{\mu_{\wp(X)}}{\mapsto}\cup\{\mathcal A_i\mid i\in I\}\stackrel{\mu_X}{\mapsto}\cup(\cup\{\mathcal A_i\mid i\in I\})$$

Here the following statements are equivalent:

- $x\in\cup(\cup\{\mathcal A_i\mid i\in I\})$
- $\exists y\;[x\in y\in\cup\{\mathcal A_i\mid i\in I\}]$
- $\exists y\exists i\in I\; [x\in y\wedge y\in\mathcal A_i]$
- $\exists y[x\in y\wedge\exists i\in I\;[y\in\mathcal A_i]$
- $\exists y[x\in y\in\cup\mathcal A_i]$
- $x\in\cup\{\cup\mathcal A_i\mid i\in I\}$

This proves the commutativity of the diagram.

Comment: Thank you @drhab. I suppose each $\mathcal{A}_{i}$ belongs to $\mathcal{P}^{2}(X)$. If that is so, then how do we still have it in $\mathcal{P}(X)$? How does $x\in \mathcal{P}(X)$ belong to $$\bigcup(\bigcup\{\mathcal{A}_{i}:i\in I\})$$?

Comment: From $\mathcal A_i\in\wp^2(X)$ or equivalently $\mathcal A_i\subseteq\wp(X)$ it follows that $\cup\mathcal A_i\subseteq X$. The fifth bullet tells us that some $y$ exists with $x\in y\in\cup\mathcal A_i$. So we have $x\in y\in X$ or equivalently $x\in\wp(X)$.